# Search dialog in android is not showing

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application where I want to implement a search dialog.
Despite following all the steps in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

On clicking the search icon no search dialog appears. The code is as follows:

**Android manifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.a1405232.rateit2">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".HomePage"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_home_page"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>

            <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                    android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
            </activity>
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </application>
```

**HomePage.java**

```
package com.example.a1405232.rateit2;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;

    public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        Intent i1 = getIntent();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_page, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

            switch(id)
            {
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    return true;

                case R.id.action_search:
                    onSearchRequested();


                    //          Toast.makeText(this, "This is my Toast message!",
            //                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                default:
                    // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                    // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                // Handle the camera action
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**SearchableActivity.java**

```
package com.example.a1405232.rateit2;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v, int position, long id) {
        // call detail activity for clicked entry
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query =intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doSearch(query);
        }
    }

    private void doSearch(String queryStr) {
        // get a Cursor, prepare the ListAdapter and set it
    }

}
```

There's a searchable.xml in res/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

What am I missing out on?
I have not yet implemented query yet. Just want the SearchableActivity to
open so that I can see the search dialog.

I saw this answer and added an external meta tag but no response [Search in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710985/search-in-android?s=2|2.7198)

This is how the screen looks. No search box appears on clicking the search icon.

[image: search box is not showing]

Answer (score 3):

following is the basic code for a working search dialog example.

First of all u have to define a `searchable.xml` file in the `xml` resource folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Please be careful, for the `label` and `hint` values are **mandatory** they point to string resources, this is a point that should be highlighted more in the android documentation and still is the source of so many issues.

Second, you have to change a bit your `AndroidManifest.xml`, let's suppose for sake of simplicity that you just have one activity `MainActivity`, your manifest at the end should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.paolomoschini.searchdialogtest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- this is the searchable activity; it performs searches. 
            Notice that this provides the search dialog by default -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                       android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The last step is to change the `MainActivity.class` for show the search dialog and receive the search query.
Let's suppose you have a menu item with the following items declared:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      tools:context="com.paolomoschini.searchdialogtest.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

The `MainActivity.class` should trigger the following when user press on the search icon

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            //this is the method that displays the search dialog
            onSearchRequested();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

`MainActivity.class` receive the search text throught an intent, in your `onCreate` method add the following:

```
    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Log.v("QUERY", query);
    }
```

Comment: You save my life with "label and hint values are mandatory they point to string resources", I can't understand why and why it isn't in the docs with big uppercase red letters :D